# shell script wiork on console but not from php page

Tags: php, bash, shell

I have a problem, I need to launch a .sh script from a web page, just does not go, starting from the terminal the script works and does what it has to do, but from the web no, but in the ' Apache2 error.log does not make any mistakes, I do not understand what it can be ..

HTML:

```html
    <tr>
        <td>JTS</td>
        <td>
            <form action="JTSstart.php">
            <input type="submit" value="START">
            </form>
        </td>
                <td>
            <form action="JTSres.php">
            <input type="submit" value="RESTART">
            </form>
        </td>
                <td>
            <form action="JTSstop.php">
            <input type="submit" value="STOP">
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

PHP:

```html
<?php
echo exec('bash JTSstop.sh');
sleep(5);
header("Location: 5ondimba.html");
?>
```

SH:

```html
#!/bin/bash
cd  /home/otaku/JTS3ServerMod_HostingEdition
./jts3servermod_startscript.sh stop
```

What I have tried / tested:
1) The exec command, such as shell_exec, is not disabled in the php setup.
2) The files were converted with dos2unix.
3) bash -x on the script and does not report any kind of error (in fact, from console works).

what could it be?? how can i make it work?
Thanks so much!

Comment: Your PHP-Script need `executable rights`! Check the `chmod` of the PHP-File and check your WebServer, which user will be used for exutement.

Comment: `echo exec('bash JTSstop.sh');` - you are just "echo"ing, not executing.

Comment: @AdrianPreuss i dont think that it is a permission problem, it would tell me something in the log, anyway i have checked and i think its all ok

Comment: @Don'tPanic someone advised me to use "echo", but also if i take it off, nothing change

Comment: No, `it's a permission problem`! I had used same things on older projects to start/restart/stop services on an webinterface. Check the permissions and smile. You can check, if you have an permission problem, if you using other commands, like `ls` or `hostname` - If you get an result, for sample, you knowing, that your script is not reachable with your actual permissions-setup.

Comment: @AdrianPreuss the dir "/home" have 755, all subfolders up to the file "jts3servermod_startscript.sh" have 777, like the latter

Comment: `chmod` is not all. Which user/group will be used? Try to use `chgrp`/`chown` to `www-data`, for example. Otherwise you can add the executable-permission on WebServer's `Environment`. Other references, with the same problem: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115054/php-shell-exec-permission-on-linux-ubuntu

Comment: i only have the root user, because im the only one that use the machine, the user/group that are setted is "root". i trying to do something that they say on your link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few problems:

1) Get rid of `echo`.  At best, it will display output of the command (if there is any), but if that happens it will cause your subsequent `header()` to fail - `header()` must be called before any output is generated.

2) PATHs are not the same in PHP as in your SHELL on the console.  Don't assume `bash` or `JTSstop.sh` are in PHP's PATH, or in PHP's current working directory.  Better to always fully specify paths.

3) Your script already includes `#!/bin/bash`, no need to call it with `bash` again.

PHP:

```
<?php
exec('/full/path/to/JTSstop.sh');
sleep(5);
header("Location: 5ondimba.html");
?>
```

But why not keep things simple and get rid of `JTSstop.sh` all together?

```
<?php
exec('cd /home/otaku/JTS3ServerMod_HostingEdition; ./jts3servermod_startscript.sh stop');
sleep(5);
header("Location: 5ondimba.html");
?>
```

If you're still having problems, you can see the results of the `exec` by specifying a 2nd parameter, [as described in the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php).

```
<?php
exec('cd /home/otaku/JTS3ServerMod_HostingEdition; ./jts3servermod_startscript.sh stop', $output);
print_r($output);
```

Comment: i have take out "echo", i have added the fully paths of jtsstop.sh but now work anyway, finally i try to keep all things on the exec('...'); but anyway not work :c in all cases there arent nothing error in log

Comment: @Flynns82 you can always grab the output to find what happened.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: with the $output i see that the pid of jts was bugged o.o now i have solved all, the problem was on the program that i have needed to start.. thanks for all!!

Comment: of course!, anyway i need a little help with a similar thing, i need to run another program but it need a screen, what i need to add to to prevent closure at the end of script execution?

Comment: Not sure what you mean ... closure of what?

Comment: honestly I do not know, when i start this program i need to create a screen, launch the program and close putty(if i need to do another thing) because if i clic ctrl^c, the programm would close, now i see on the $output that the program will start, but it closes immediately

Comment: `create a screen` - what does that mean?  Are you talking about the [screen terminal window manager](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/)?

Comment: Something like https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162133/run-script-in-a-screen?

Comment: @Don'tPanic : I think the reasoning you give for your recommendation (1) is not entirely correct. Maybe you confuse the PHP echo command with the shell echo command? `echo` in PHP evaluates the argument and outputs its result to stdout. It *would* make sense to use echo for diagnostics, *if* the OP would use it together with `shell_exec`. Of course, with just `exec` it is of no use, but the reason why, is different from what you posted.

Comment: @user1934428 You are quite right! I either confused BASH/PHP echo or thought the argument was quoted, my mistake. I've updated my answer.  Thanks for catching and correcting me.